# Drupal hook_form_alter weight control

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fapi

Try to add some additional form items in the new content type add form.

Also try to increase the weight of submit and preview there.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  //add some $form items here

  $form['actions']['submit']['#weight'] = 2000;
  $form['actions']['preview']['#weight'] = 2001;
}
```

But somehow the submit and preview buttons are still above the new items added there.

Comment: Try setting the weights of the items you want to be higher to be a lower number? Also, this question belongs in [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/?as=1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add the `#weight` property to `$form['actions']` wrapper.

Your current code changes the weight for the 2 buttons inside the `actions wrapper`, and doesn't affect the weight for the wrapper.

E.g. see the following code:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    //add some $form items here

    $form['actions']['#weight'] = 2000;
}
```

Hope this works.